# How to 'return' value in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have written program, which calculates how much odd numbers given list contains.
In order to use it, you need to type your query in this form `knelyg([1,2,3],K).`. Here is my issue, now, my program would return `false`, rather then `K=2`.

My question is, how to make sure that K value would be returned to user and printed out without using any write functions in program itself?

```
calc(S,K):-
    S = [First|Tail],
    (First rem 2 =:= 0 -> calc(Tail,K); K1 is K + 1),
    calc(Tail,K1).

 knelyg(S,K):-
    K = 0,
    calc(S,K).
```

Comment: Your `knelyg` query fails because it initially unifies `K = 0`, then queries `calc(S, K)`. If `calc(S, K)` tries to unify `K` with anything other than 0, it will fail. If you need to start at some value, one way is to pass it as an extra argument, such as `calc(S, K0, K)` where `K0` is the starting value. Or, from `knelyg`, you can directly query `calc(S, 0, K)`.

Comment: There are several other issues, too. For example, in `calc(S, K)` you start with `S = [First|Tail]`, then have `First rem 2 =:= 0`. But `First isn't instantiated. So `First rem 2 =:= 0` is going to fail due to an uninstantiated variable. Start by thinking about two cases: a recursive case, and a base case. The base case is the empty list: `knelyg([], 0).` which says, *the empty list has 0 odd elements*. Then the recursive case would be, `knelyg([First|Tail], N) :- knelyg(Tail, N1), ... [figure out N from here]`.

Comment: @lurker - you have been a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: Work hard on finding better predicate names than `calc/2` and `knelyg/2`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep it simple... could be

```
knelyg([],0). % missing base case
knelyg([First|Tail],K):-
    knelyg(Tail,K1),
    K is K1+(First rem 2).
```